# Create a function that returns a shared pointer to an object of a class template

Tags: c++

I want to create a function that returns the shared pointer of an object of a template class:

```
#include <memory>

template <class T>
class Rectangular
{
public:

    virtual  T& getHight()  = 0;
    virtual  T& getWidth()  = 0;
    virtual  Rectangular<std::shared_ptr<T>>*  getPtr()  = 0;



};

template <class T>
class Square:public Rectangular<T>
{
public:
    Square() {};
    Square(T hight, T width) :m_hight(hight), m_width(width) {};
     T& getHight()  ;
     T& getWidth()  ;
     Square<std::shared_ptr<T>>* getPtr() ;

public:
    T m_hight;
    T m_width;

};

template <class T> 
 T& Square<T>::getHight()  { return m_hight; };

template <class T>
 T& Square<T>::getWidth()   { return m_width; };

template <class T>
Square<std::shared_ptr<T>>*  Square<T>::getPtr() { return this; };


int main()
{

    Square <double> sq(5,3);

    std::cout << sq.getPtr()->getHight();

    return 0;

}
```

This is the runtime error that i get:
recursive type or function dependency context too complex.

Can someone help me find out what is happening?

Comment: That doesn't look like a runtime error.

Comment: I get [a slightly different error message](https://ideone.com/r0REPH).

Comment: You using visual studio?

Comment: When asking about errors, please include the *full* and *complete* error, copy-pasted as text (if possible, and for build errors there's almost always a way to get it as text). Also add comments in the [mcve] to show us where the errors are. Lastly please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Aris No, I use ideone, which is a website. You can follow the link for more details.

Comment: @melpomene  I get the same output as you but also the error that i show earlier.

Comment: Are you sure you want to deal with `shared_ptr<double>` (shared doubles) and parameterize `Rectangular`s with such a shared double? To me it rather looks like you want a shared Rectangular than a shared double? In that case your type has to be `shared_ptr<Rectangular<T>>`. And then have a look at [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this).

Comment: @sebrockm note that inheriting `std::enable_shared_from_this` implies that *every* instance is owned by a `shared_ptr`, which is not the case for `sq` in `main` here

Comment: @Caleth I'm fully aware that just putting it into OP's code would require some more changes to make it work. This was a comment, not a fully working answer ;-) I was just trying to figure out what OP really wants. Note, that he is returning `this` in `getPtr()`. All in all, except for the order of words in `Square<shared_ptr>` vs. `shared_ptr<Square>`, it looks pretty much like he actually wants to share a rectangle rather than a double.

Comment: @sebrockm Actually yes. I am doing it with rectangles and squares just to try out but what i wanted to do is to create an object which would share ownership of the same pointer with all its derived classes. But anyway thank you i will have to see more carrefully some things before going there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn this declaration

```
Square<std::shared_ptr<T>>* getPtr() ;
```

To this one

```
Rectangular<std::shared_ptr<T>>* getPtr() ;
```

Why? Because while C++ allows covariant return types, to check for covariance the complete object type we are pointing at is required (the class's bases are only visible in complete types). That necessitates an instantiation, and then exactly what [**Sombrero Chicken** answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54868341/817643) happens.

But if you don't use a covaraint return type, the specializations you name don't *need* to be complete. Because we can form pointers to incomplete class types, after all. In general. so long as the complete object type is not required, naming a specialization won't instantiate the class. That avoids the infinite recursion.

I won't repeat the other excellent points the other answers contain about your design. This is solely to let you know what is the root cause.

Answer (score 4):

You can't magic up shared ownership from nowhere. `Rectangular::getPtr` isn't going to work. There is no `shared_ptr` to get from `sq`, it is *uniquely* owned by `main`.

You also seem confused about how to combine templates. `Square<std::shared_ptr<T>>` is a square where the width and height are `std::shared_ptr<T>`s, presumably pointing to unrelated data. You *probably* mean `std::shared_ptr<Square<T>>`, which is an object representing a share of ownership of a square.

Finally, whilst it might be mathematically the case that all squares are rectangles, you cannot use modifiable squares interchangeably with modifiable rectangles. By definition the width and height of a square are equal. Changing the width of a rectangle should not change it's height.

There is a contradiction in those two requirements.

Comment: I am mostly trying to learn C++ so the classes that i use are random. No mathematical conection or somethin like this

Comment: If you are learning C++, forget that `std::shared_ptr<T>` exists. You don't need it at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

```
template <class T>
Square<std::shared_ptr<T>>*  Square<T>::getPtr() { return this; }
```

This will return a `Square<std::shared_ptr<T>>*` where `T` is a `double`, so `Square<std::shared_ptr<double>>*`. The compiler has to go and instantiate this template for `Square` for you.

This new instantiation also has a method `getPtr` which now returns a `Square<std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<double>>*`. The compiler has to go and instantiate this template for `Square` for you.

Repeat this process until the compiler is done with your bamboozling or blows up.

---

This is infinitely recursive and can never work. You should rethink your design.

Comment: Naming a specialization is not enough to instantiate it. It has to be used in a way that requires a complete object type. A pointer delcarator does not.

Comment: @StoryTeller The call to it surely does, no?

Comment: Yes, that will instantiate a single extra specialization. To instantiate the next one, we'll need to add another call to `getPtr`. No call, no instantiation.

Comment: @StoryTeller Why does [GCC's output seem to look for an infinite specialization in that case then](https://ideone.com/r0REPH)? (I'm sure you're right I'm just not sure why the compiler does that)

Comment: I wouldn't rule out a GCC bug. Ideone uses GCC 6.3, no?

Comment: Well that's interesting.

Comment: @StoryTeller Same results on tio.run (gcc 8.2.1).

Comment: And on wandbox for clang. Seems like not just GCC.

Comment: Mmm, interesting. There could be something else that requires a complete object type here. But golly, I don't see it.

Comment: @StoryTeller Now I'm curious and you're better than me at this so I'll await your answer.

Comment: Well, here's to make sure I haven't lost my marbles (https://wandbox.org/permlink/rVDUpVDCNEJMxp5k). Replacing  `shared_ptr` with another template behaves as expected. Might be an implementation detail we are running afowl of (:P)

Comment: It seems to be related to `virtual Rectangular<std::shared_ptr<T>>*  getPtr()  = 0;` in the base class.

Comment: @Sombrero Chicken  Yes, I am sorry , thats a compiler error , C1202

Comment: @StoryTeller Interesting hmm.. What could even trigger that inside an implementation. All major compilers (GCC, Clang and VC++) are giving me an error on using `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @StoryTeller As melpomene says, its apparently something to do with the virtual specifier. Try replacing `shared_ptr` with your empty `contain` class in the old code and it'll still trigger the error. Maybe there's a language standard rule about this.

Comment: @melpomene - Is on to the mcve (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c78edc8cb7f516b). A virtual function is implicitly odr-used. But I don't recall it needing to cause *that*.

Comment: Maybe the compiler is trying to determine whether `Square<T>::getPtr` is a valid override of `Rectangle<T>::getPtr` (if it isn't, `Square<double> sq;` is an error).

Comment: @melpomene - That's it! The co-variant return type requires a completely defined object type to establish an inheritance relationship .

Comment: SO IN THE END MY ANSWER IS CORRECT.. Or something.

Comment: Well yes, but that's not to say one can't have their cake and eat it too. Replacing the covariant return type by the exact return type of the base class takes us back to sanity http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ee0998ebadf6271 (or something resembling sanity, anyway)

Comment: @StoryTeller Sanity and C++. Pick one.

Comment: I made my choice long ago.